# Regex issue - fine backwards and not forwards Textmate

Tags: regex, textmate, oniguruma

I'm not very good with regular expressions but in Textmate, I'm trying to clear out some multi-lines in an XML file that looks like

```
<comments>
    <sub_node>....
....
</comments>
```

and I'm using this in the find/replace with regex,

```
<comments>(?m:.*)</comments>
```

There're multiple occurences of the above, but if I do a find, it finds the first  and then selects everything in between including outside nodes till the last  in the file.

If I do a find previous (backwards) from the last line it captures a block correctly. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here and if anyone might even suggest a far more efficient way of doing this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use non-greedy qualifiers. I don't know anything about Textmate, so I don't know if it supports them. If it doesn't, you can search for `<comments>` followed by any number of things that isn't `</comments>` followed by `<comments>`. (This would be more specific help, but your posted example is unfamiliar and must be some Textmate weirdness.)

Comment: yea, thanks for the info, guess I have to do it more specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like perfectly normal behavior to me.  You just need to use a reluctant quantifier, which means adding a `?`, like so:

```
<comments>(?m:.*?)</comments>
```

The only weirdness here is the `m` (for "multiline") modifier, which allows the `.` metacharacter to match newlines.  Most regex flavors call that "single-line" or "dot-matches-all" mode, and use `s` to specify it.  Those flavors tend to support an `m`/"multiline" mode as well, which changes the behavior of the `^` and `$` [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).  In TextMate that's the default mode, and can't be changed.